# no record selected with the following query

Tags: sql, qt

```
  query.prepare("SELECT invoice FROM " + m_invoiceInfoTable + " WHERE invalid='' AND invoice IN (SELECT invoice FROM " + m_invoiceUserTable + " WHERE user=:user)");
```

Is there any problem with this query ?
I had not set the invalid field and still its not giving any record corresponding to ths

Comment: You should debug the values of **m_invoiceUserTable**, **m_invoiceInfoTable** and **:user**. Then try to run the query in a console.

Comment: Does the `invalid` field allows `NULL`? Perhaps you can try with `invalid IS NULL` instead of `invalid=''`.

Comment: thanks a lot :) It solved by 'IS NULL'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to say with

```
invalid=''
```

Are you saying that invalid is defined as an empty string or that invalid is null (undefined) which would be done as

```
invalid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:
`query.prepare("SELECT invoice FROM " + m_invoiceInfoTable + " WHERE invalid is null AND invoice IN (SELECT invoice FROM " + m_invoiceUserTable + " WHERE user=:user)");`
It is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators, such as =, <, or <>.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT invoice FROM " + m_invoiceInfoTable + " 
WHERE ISNULL(invalid, '')='' AND invoice IN (SELECT invoice FROM " + m_invoiceUserTable + " WHERE user=:user)
```

Whats the data type of invalid, is it a char, string, bit or int and so on. is it nullable?

Comment: I am sorry but it didnt worked, although it is solved using above solutions
But can you tell me what the isnull returns?

Comment: the data type of invalid is string

Comment: ISNULL will return the value of invalid if it's not null otherwise it will return the second specified value eg: `ISNULL(invalid, 'abc')` would return 'abc' when invalid was NULL, however it's worth pointing out that blank ('') is not the same as NULL